# Angular Change Detection On Push

Tags: angular, angular13

I am trying to invoice change detection on the changing params page. After that, I get recipe JSON from DB.
Why my code doesn't invoice component change detection when I create a new Subscription in the ngOnInit?

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { RecipesApiService } from '../../../services/recipes/recipes-api.service';
import { IRecipeApi } from '../../../services/recipes/recipes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-page',
  templateUrl: './recipe-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-page.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class RecipePageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  recipe!: IRecipeApi;
  private sub$!: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private recipesApiService: RecipesApiService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub$ = this.route.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params) => {
          return this.recipesApiService.getRecipeApiById(params['id']);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((recipe) => {
        this.recipe = recipe;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see your template. However, you can manually execute change detection injecting ChangeDetectorRef in your constructor and using it like this.cd.detectChanges();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it? With `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you have to manually invoke change detection. That's the whole point of using it. In your code you don't do so, hence the change detection is not invoked.

Read more about change detection in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes), or refer to one of the multiple tutorials available on the web.

Comment: Yes I know it, the question is how can I invoke it?

Comment: Why does the Subscription won't invoke it?

Comment: Everything is explained in the linked docs, even with an example. You inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in the constructor, and call `.markForCheck()` when you want to run change detection - in your case inside the subscription, after you updated the value of `this.recipe`.

Comment: I thought the sub$ will invoke it.. well i got wrong about it.

Comment: The documentation is something publicly available and anyone who reads it, might get more doubts hence the question was asked.this answer is not simplying it,just linking resources